# How frequent does latitude-longitude change over a period of 10 to 20 years

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a MySql DB with lat-long stored probably 10 years ago.
Now am using this lat-long for a given zip to provide a **map-marker** in android app. The stakeholder are complaining that the **marker is inaccurate**. 
In other-words, the lat-long am providing to the Mobile app via an API from MySql DB is (or maybe) obsolete.

The company that am working for is surely **more than 10 years old**. They have stored lat-long values against ZIP codes in a MySql DB. 
No, they have not updated the lat-long in the past years.

I understand there are different reference frames available like WGS84, NAD83 etc when it comes to finding lat-long.

Am not sure of 'how' or 'from where' the 1st team that build this website took the lat-long for storing in DB.
I want to know the **probability** that am dealing with an **obsolete lat-long** or may be how much obsolete or miss-match can these cause.

Comment: Look up "plate motion", which is one cause of natural drift in geographic coordinates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about programming.  A better place to ask this may be GIS.stackexchange.com

Comment: The coordinates may move, either by continental drift or introduction/update of new coordinate system or reference frames. However, such changes are typically in range of centimeters or max in range of a few meters. For mapping against ZIP codes such inaccuracy should not matter at all.

Comment: Alright makes sense. I will close this question.
Thanks @PeterO. and Wernfried Domscheit